# c++ what is the correct syntax here?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

what is the correct syntax for checking a varable value and then setting a varable in the same condition also checking that new set varables var, all in one if statement?

so basically something like

```
if(this->somevar > 0 && this->newvar = this->GetNewVar(this->somevar),this->newvar > 0)
```

i know that is not the correct syntax or at least its not working for me anyway, hence the topic, i am using that as an example, so if `this->somevar` is null or 0, i don't want it to execute the next condition which is `&& this->newvar = this->GetNewVar(this->somevar,this->newvar` but instead skip the statement and ignore that part.

what is the correct syntax for something like this?

Comment: It's already fine. operator && has got short-circuit semantics. If the left-hand condition is false, it stops right there, since the full expression can never be true.

Comment: Why do you wanna do such thing? Why not nested `if`s?

Comment: Is this code in a derived template class or something? It would be a lot more readable if you were able to omit all the `this->`.

Comment: When you know how to do things in two statements, but not in one, then it is a very strong indication that you should write it in two statements, since it gets incomprehensible in one.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Agreed. There is usually no appreciable benefit in rolling two statements like this into one. You'll probably end up with code that's more difficult to read and therefore maintain. Also, if you assign within your conditional, it's likely you'll get compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the logical AND `&&` operator is short-circuited if `this->somevar` evaluates to zero, meaning the rest of your **if** expression would not be evaluated in that situation

Answer (score 4):

`&&` is an operator with short circuit evaluation, right part is not executed if left part is true.
But why don't you simply write:

```
if(this->somevar > 0)
{
  this->newvar = this->GetNewVar(this->somevar);
  if (this->newvar > 0)
  {
    ...
```

This will certainly makes things clearer ...

Comment: The usual parlance is that `&&` has "short circuit behaviour". "Sequential operator" might be confused with "Sequence operator".

Answer (score 2):

The expression after the comma is not necessary. Also, there is one thing missing, parentheses arround the assignment:

`if(this->somevar > 0 && (this->newvar = this->GetNewVar(this->somevar)) > 0)`

Without the parentheses you may end up setting `this->newvar` to the value of the boolean expression
`this->GetNewVar(this->somevar),this->newvar > 0`, which will be evaluated to a boolean result (true/false which, in turn, may  be converted to 0 or 1 or -1 depending on the compiler, when cast to the type of `this->newvar`).

Comment: There is no point in using the comma operator, as an assignment returns the value assigned; `if (somevar > 0 && (newVar = foo()) > 0)` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I think only the bit after the comma is evaluated for the if condition. The expression on the left of the comma is ignored.

```
int main() {
        if( false, true) { cout << " got to if( false, true ) "; }
        if ( true, false ) { cout << "got to if( true, false ) "; }
}
```

to answer your question, you can put anything on the left of the comma and do whatever you like, as long as the expression you want to evaluate is the last expression in the list.

so if ( exp1, exp2, exp3 , exp4 ) dowhatever(); only gets run if exp4 is true. You should really run exp1 to exp3 outside the if condition for readability.